# How can you edit a USDZ mesh that has been included in AR project?

Tags: scenekit, arkit, maya, realitykit, usdz

How can you edit a `usdz` file and maintain the rigs that have been set inside of it? For example, I am trying to edit the robot.usdz mesh included in this example project -

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d

The robot.usdz file is included in the character folder.

I have tried the following:

1. Convert usdz > scn > dae using scntool. However the scntool fails to successfully convert the file
2. Convert usdz > stl file using ModelIO. The STL file loses all joints and does not include the geometry
3. Try adding a node to the SCN file > convert back to usdz. The robot character fails to load via RealityKit
4. Tried using the Unity usdz package manager. Did not have much success here and was not able to edit the actual geometry

Do you have a recommended pipeline for editing the actual mesh for a usdz file? I do not have an original dae or fbx or gtlf file.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily import a textured 3D model contained in `.usdz` file into Autodesk Maya 2022 with a corresponding [Pixar MayaUSD Tools](https://github.com/Autodesk/maya-usd) plug-in installed. Then edit your `.usdz` model and export it.